# Cloning bootstrap datepicker with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am trying to duplicate my bootstrap datepicker, but it's not working properly. 
The datepicker is inside a div and I duplicate the whole div. It works fine, but the datepicker is only working in the original div, not the cloned ones.
I've seen on stackoverflow that you can put a class instead of an Id, but that is not working either.

```js
$('.calendar').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
});

function duplicate() {
  var i = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.id = "new";
  d.innerHTML = i.innerHTML;
  var p = document.getElementById('dynamicInput');
  p.appendChild(d);
}

duplicate();
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" integrity="sha256-I/m6FhcACNYmRoqn1xUnizh6S7jOJsTq+aiJ6BtE2LE=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" integrity="sha256-7Ls/OujunW6k7kudzvNDAt82EKc/TPTfyKxIE5YkBzg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="dynamicInput" class="col-md-12">
  <div id="duplicater">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="field-wrap3 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Event Title" name="event_title[]">
      </div>
      <div class="field-wrap3 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Background Image (URL)" name="img_url[]">
      </div>
      <div class="field-wrap3 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <input name="date" placeholder="Date" type="text" class="calendar" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="description-create" class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="description[]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't get why it's not working. My JavaScript selects all the elements with the class calendar and "gives" it a datepicker, does it not?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem. If I clone the div manually, it works properly. If I clone the div with my button, it doesn't. I think it comes from the fact that javascript is already initialized when I clone my div, so it doesn't take into account my new divs with the class "calendar". 
How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem give same class name of your second input field as your original and initialize datepicker with same class name,  you don't need to duplicate whole code.

For example if you want to initialize datetimepicker in two textbox just give them same name as in example that follows in snippet.

```
 
$( function() {
    $( ".calendar" ).datepicker();
} );
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input name="date" placeholder="Date" type="text" class="calendar"/>
<input name="date1" placeholder="Date1" type="text" class="calendar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure to understand, should I give a different name to each input ? I think I can't do that. As I need to clone the whole div, my input always has the same name ...

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working. When I inspect my code, the duplicated input has the same class (.calendar). So the datepicker should work ...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem. If I clone the div manually, it works properly. If I clone the div with my button, it doesn't. I think it comes from the fact that javascript is already initialized when I clone my div, so it doesn't take into account my new divs with the class "calendar". 
How can I solve that ?

Comment: That is  exactly the problem  dom does not contain your second input so  that is problem of  event delegation please refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zybq9BE1hg

Answer (score 0):

The order of operations that you are using is:

- html is on page
- you are telling datepicker to enable the existing instances of `.calendar`
- you are copying the div which creates html that the previous call didn't know about, so nothing attaches to it

The copy is making a copy of the html, it is not creating a new instance of datepicker. If at the end of your copy you called `$('.calendar').datepicker('destroy');` you could follow that by your existing call to:

```
$('.calendar').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
});
```

which would have the effect of:

- html is on page
- datepicker is attached to all existing instances of `.calendar`
- duplicate is called

  - duplicate copies the html
  - and removes all instances of .calendar
  - and then reattaches to make sure it gets the original and the new instances of calendar

alternatively you could scope your call for attaching datepicker so that you attach it only to the newly created html.